# Does a set of all decimal expansions of $\pi$ contains $\pi?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers, pi, decimal-expansion

Let's say there is a set containing all finite decimal expansions of [$\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi):

$$A = \{3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159, ... \}$$

Does this set contains $\pi$?

I see that it is probably not true because then it would may mean that $\pi$ is a rational number. But, since it's an infinite set, there is no "last" element of this set. Therefore I am confused. Someone please guide on the same.

Comment: All elements in $A$ are rational numbers, but $\pi$ is not rational. However, $\pi=\sup A$, the closest thing to a last element

Comment: A good example of why the completeness axiom on reals is nontrivial

Comment: "there is no "last" element of this set." That's correct, but why do you think this means that $\pi$ is in the set (it doesn't)?

Comment: Does $\{1,2,3,4,5,\dots\}$ contain $\infty$, zolv? Does the open interval $(0,3)$ contain $3$?

Comment: $A$ contains only numbers with a finite decimal expansion (by definition) , hence $\pi$ (having no finite decimal expansion) cannot be an element of $A$.